# Getting Child Component Input Data to Parent, gathering into Array in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

** For example, here, when I click the button, I will have one more component, it means it will have new data, so I want to gather all info into one array when I press Save Data button, I hope,it's pretty straightforward to understand

```
<Child v-for="count in btnNumber" :key="count" @showData="getElements" />

<v-btn
  color="primary"
  elevation="10"
  class="space"
  large
  @click="duplicateEl"
  >Add Categ & Key</v-btn
>
v-btn
      color="secondary"
      elevation="13"
      class="btnEl"
      dark
      large
      @click="getResult"
      >Save Data</v-btn
```

** It's  getting data from my child component using Emit

```
methods:{
               getElements(emitPayload) {
              this.selectedChildCategory = emitPayload.selectedCateg;
              this.selectedChildKey = emitPayload.selectedKey;
              this.selectedChildLanguage = emitPayload.selectedLang;
              this.selectedChildContent = emitPayload.selectedCon;
        }
    }
 duplicateEl() {
  this.btnNumber++;
}
```

[image: Here is my form please help, I appreciate it]

[image: What if I want to add nested child to child component?]

Comment: Try saving the data on emit (from get elements)  to a new data variable  array, and use that array

Comment: yeah what about if I duplicate the Child Component?it means I need duplicated overall result. If you look at the picture, I want to duplicate child component and save all input result into array at once

Comment: Same, first do a check, if its same index or key (it depends on your check value), then update, else do a push

Comment: can you give me some example? I'm beginner in Vue hope you understand

Comment: I appreciate your answer my friend! Below answer is the exact answer I need thanks!

Comment: Marked answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hold data on parent component, pls take a look at following snippet:

```js
Vue.component('Child', {
  template: `
  <v-form>
    <v-container>
      <v-row>
        <v-col>
          <v-select
            :items="categories"
            label="Category"
            dense
            outlined
            v-model="content.cat"
            @change="setD"
          ></v-select>
          </v-col>
          <v-col>
          <v-select
            :items="keys"
            label="Key"
            dense
            outlined
            v-model="content.key"
            @change="setD"
          ></v-select>
          </v-col>
          <v-col>
          <v-select
            :items="langs"
            label="Lang"
            dense
            outlined
            v-model="content.lang"
            @change="setD"
          ></v-select>
          </v-col>
          <v-col>
          <v-select
            :items="contents"
            label="Cont"
            dense
            outlined
            v-model="content.cont"
            @change="setD"
          ></v-select>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-form>
  `,
  props: ['conte'],
  data() {
    return {
      content: this.conte,
      categories: ['first', 'second', 'third'],
      keys: [1,2,3],
      langs: ['g', 'h', 'j'],
      contents: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
    }
  },
  methods: {
   setD() {
      this.$emit('show', this.content);
    },
  },
})

new Vue({
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      contentFields: [{id: 0, cat: '', key: '', lang: '', cont: ''}],
      showData: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addInput() {
      let newI = this.contentFields.length 
      this.contentFields.push({id: newI, cat: '', key: '', lang: '', cont: ''})
    },
    getElements(e){
      const newData = this.contentFields.map(obj => {
        if(obj.id === e.id) 
           return { ...obj }
        return obj
      });
    },
    getResult() {
      this.showData = !this.showData
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-container>
          <v-btn
            color="primary"
            elevation="10"
            class="space"
            large
            @click="addInput"
          >Add Categ & Key</v-btn>
          <v-container v-for="(content, i) in contentFields" :key="i">
            <child :conte="content" @show="getElements" />
          </v-container>
          <v-btn
            color="secondary"
            elevation="13"
            class="btnEl"
            dark
            large
            @click="getResult"
          >Save Data</v-btn>
          <div v-if="showData">{{ contentFields }}</div>
        </v-container>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: dude sorry for bothering, what if I want to have nested child? Please check the last image, I would be really thankful, if a bit update your answer

Comment: I wanna to add nested child component and values each time user add new nested child component.      [ { "id": 0, "cat": "", "key": "", "lang": "", "cont": "", "childlang": "", "childCon": "" } ][ { "id": 0, "cat": "", "key": "", "lang": "", "cont": "", "childlang": "", "childCon": "" "childlang": "", "childCon": "" " } ]

Answer (score 1):

Try saving the data on emit event (from get elements) to a new data variable array, and use that array

```
<template>
      <div>
        <Child
          v-for="count in btnNumber"
          :key="count"
          @showData="getElements(count)"
        />
        <!-- BUTTONS HERE -->
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          elementsEmmitedDataArray: [], // array
        };
      },
      methods: {
        getElements(countIndex, emitPayload) {
          const data = {
            uniqueIndex: countIndex, //or anything unique for each Child component
            selectedChildCategory: emitPayload.selectedCateg,
            selectedChildKey: emitPayload.selectedKey,
            selectedChildLanguage: emitPayload.selectedLang,
            selectedChildContent: emitPayload.selectedCon,
          };
          // check if uniqindex is already exist in array then update it else push new data
            const index = this.elementsEmmitedDataArray.findIndex(
                (element) => element.uniqueIndex === countIndex
            );
            if (index !== -1) {
                this.elementsEmmitedDataArray[index] = data;
            } else {
                this.elementsEmmitedDataArray.push(data);
            }
        },
        duplicateEl() {
          this.btnNumber++;
        },
    
        submitData(){
            // use the array 
            console.log(this.elementsEmmitedDataArray);
        }
    
      },
    };
    </script>
```